# MVC4 security issue for a Telerik project template

Tags: security, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem with the AccountModel setup with MVC 4.

I created a Telerik MVC 4 project and then tried to implement the AccountModel setup that Microsoft has for an MVC 4 project template and am receiving the below error: It has a public key token and appears to be a stnongly typed assembly.

```
"The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartcode threw and exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version 4.0.0.0'"
```

If I create the Microsoft MVC 4 project template with security as a stand alone project, no issues...

How do I get by this error and incorporate it into my Telerik project?

btw, not sure if I installed them or they were there when the project was created, but the following packages exist for the project and are in my reference list. It says it's having issues with the 4.0 version in my original post.

```
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to DotNetOpenAuth.Core into your project? The error is pretty clear.

Comment: yes, I did. got installed via the packages in my last edit.

Comment: Nevermind on this one.... I just used my old asp.net membership certifications from an mvc 3 project. The MVC 4 has a LOT more in it when it comes to secuirty. It's a lot to get to know...